# Matching SPI Wire Length for Multiple Devices

Tags: spi

I have a main PCB write to 5 different flash memory chips. Four of them are on their own PCBs and are connected by 6 inches of wire from the main PCB. One flash chip is on the main PCB itself and very close to the microcontroller. Each of the four external PCBs also has an accelerometer on it on the same SPI bus.

I can read/write to the external flash chips just fine, but when I have everything connected I can't read/write anything to the onboard flash chip. On the scope I see that the onboard flash chip just never responds on the MISO line(clock, chip select, and MOSI are all correct). If I remove any of the external PCBs, then I will be able to write to the onboard flash chip.

I found the solution that if I unsolder the onboard flash chip and set it up 6" of wire away on a breadboard with all of the same connections it will work. Does SPI need some type of length matching for the wires? Otherwise why does the onboard flash only work when it is further away?

Comment: Ah, if your SPI speed is under 10MHz, then using arbitrary long wires shorter than 30cm shouldbe OK. I also play with SPI accelero ADXL345 with wires about 1m, but speed 1MHz or 400/100/50kHz. So I would suggest you lower speed if problem disappears. My ADXL345 can be SPI or I2C, and I found I2C makes more trouble, because of the 400pF capacitance limit of a single I2C bus, so you need to fiddle with pull ups etc. But each SPI device's CS line is not shared, so it clean an have less wiring, picking up noise problems. / to continue, ...

Comment: I have 10 x ADXL345 acceleeros in hands, and I am using Rpi4B buster's 3 SPI buses (out of 5) and CS0 to CS2 for testing. So far so good.